# Is there any reason to not use JSONP?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, rest, jsonp

I am developing a REST client which will talk to a project management service called [attask](http://www.attask.com).

Their REST API is convenient because it returns simple JSON that is easy to use in my code. Because of this I decided to build the interface with jQuery. I quickly discovered that I cannot use AJAX from my site to the Attask API because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

My first thought was to develop a server-side rest client using [RESTSharp](http://restsharp.org/) that would act as a bridge between my javascript and the Attask API.

Before I could get started with that implementation I discovered [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). This is new to me. It turns out that the Attask API supports JSONP. jQuery supports JSONP natively so suddenly I'm back to making a complete jQuery interface with no need for server-side intervention.

My question is, is there a reason not to use JSONP? Would there be any benefit to going the extra mile and building the server-side REST client and using real AJAX calls?

Comment: I would have thought JSONP is perfectly fine. Unless your requirements are such that you want to do some processing of the request or response on your servers. And with the API on your servers, you then potentially have the problems of authentication, performance, scalability, etc that the other guys are taking care of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just bear in mind that JSONP is exactly what you're looking for: a workaround for the Same Origin Policy. With that will come all the security problems that the Same Origin Policy was intended to avoid. The upside is that you get to choose a specific domain that you trust. The downside is, if that domain decides to violate your trust they can now run arbitrary javascript code on your web pages, allowing them to send any information they want to their own servers.

If you trust 'em, go for it. If you don't, set up your own server-side proxy.

Comment: Very good point! I hadn't even thought of that. I also realized that authentication against their API will be a big question mark because I will have to render credentials as plain text to the browser. While I do trust Attask I think it's still enough risk and problems to merit the server-side intervention. Thanks for the feedback!